# Convert date format from "month_name day, year" to "yyyy-mm-dd" in BigQuery

Tags: python, sql, date, google-bigquery, sql-update

I have a column with date format as "month_name day, yyyy", for example, "July 4, 2000". Now I want to convert it to ISO "yyyy-mm-dd". Is there any function I can call to do it in standard SQL?

```
UPDATE target_name 
SET col = function(col)
```

How do I use python client to update a column with the above function or update a new column using the function after creating it as below ?

```
original_schema = table.schema
new_schema = original_schema[:] 
new_schema.append(bigquery.SchemaField('new_date', 'DATE'))
table.schema = new_schema
table = client.update_table(table, ['schema'])
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use date functions: [`parse_date()`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#parse_date) turns the string to a `date`, and then [`format_date()`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#format_date) converts the `date` to a string in the desired format:

```
update target_name set col = format_date('%F', parse_date('%B %e, %Y', col))
```